# Why does MIN_VERSION_GLASGOW_HASKELL not work in GHC 9.2?

Tags: haskell, ghc, preprocessor

Per [GHC guide](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/phases.html#standard-cpp-macros) we expect the `MIN_VERSION_GLASGOW_HASKELL(x,y,z,z')` CPP to work on the corresponding GHC version. However, the following fails to compile on GHC 9.2

```hs
#if MIN_VERSION_GLASGOW_HASKELL(9,2,1,0)
```

[image]

What's happening here?

---

To resolve this, I find myself using:

```hs
#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,16,0)
```

But why would `MIN_VERSION_GLASGOW_HASKELL` not work?

Comment: I've never seen this pragma before. The core libraries mostly (all?!) use the form `#if __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 902`. Maybe report this as a bug?!

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Double check you are indeed using GHC 9.2. You could even try browsing the GHC git repo to find that macro, and confirm it's wrongly defined (should require some time, but doesn't sound too hard to do). Then, I would file a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GHC versions consist of a major version, minor version, first patchlevel, and optional second patchlevel.  So GHC 9.2.1 has major 9, minor 2, first patchlevel 1, and no second patch level.

There's a bug in GHC, possibly in existence since the macro `MIN_VERSION_GLASGOW_HASKELL` was introduced, where that macro depends on a macro variable `__GLASGOW_HASKELL_PATCHLEVEL2__` which is not defined when, as is usual for release versions, the GHC version has only one patch level (like `9.2.1`).

This usually doesn't matter, except if the `-Wcpp-undef` flag is in force *AND* the test is performed on a version that matches on the major, minor, and first patch level.  Then, the check on the second patch level will generate a compiler warning message.  (Despite the fact that it looks like an "error" rather than a warning, the compilation appears to complete.)

You can work around this by:

- ignoring it -- despite appearances, it looks like it's only a warning, not an error, and compilation should complete
- shutting off `-Wcpp-undef` by either removing the flag or, if feasible, adding a `-Wno-cpp-undef` flag;
- adding some code to define the missing patchlevel before calling the macro:

  ```
   #ifndef __GLASGOW_HASKELL_PATCHLEVEL2__
   #define __GLASGOW_HASKELL_PATCHLEVEL2__ 0
   #endif
  ```

Comment: I've filed an [issue](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/21076).